# Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip Data-selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the data-selector option used for in [Twitter's Bootstrap Tooltip](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips)?  The description reads...

```
If a selector is provided, tooltip objects will be delegated to the specified targets.
```

But I don't understand its purpose or how to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the similar to using jQuery delegation methods like `on()` or `delegate()` in order to account for tooltip elements that aren't present in page when code is run.

Example binding to `body` since it is always present in page

```
$('body').tooltip({
   selector: '.mytooltipClass'

})
```

Comment: Doh! I thought it might be a way to target a different container for rendering the tooltip. I'm calling a tooltip within an element that has overflow:hidden and the tip is getting cut off.  The HTML gets rendered just after the element calling it. I was hoping to find a way to render it just before the closing body tag so when positioned it would overlay everything, but I guess that is a separate question.

Comment: looking at source of bootstrap there is no option to append to body, but likely a good feature request. Worst case you could modify bootstrap source ( beware would be future upgrade problem) and change `$tip .detach().css({ top: 0, left: 0, display: 'block' }).insertAfter(this.$element)` to `appendTo('body)`

Comment: can see actual insertion point is hard coded to insert after the hover element